# updateOrCreate only updating one record

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, model, controller

I have a list of records where I want to update the quantities with new values, but when I use the update or Create method, it only updates only one record.

```
$data = DB::table('inventory_items')->select('inventory_items.*')
    ->join('sorder_parts', 'inventory_items.id', 'sorder_parts.inventory_id')
    ->where('sorder_parts.sorder_id', '=', $id)
    ->selectraw('inventory_items.quantity - sorder_parts.quantity AS new_quantity')
    ->get();


foreach ($data as $product_item) {
    $reduce_quantity = InventoryItem::updateOrCreate(['id' => $product_item->id],
        ['quantity' => $product_item->new_quantity]);
    dd($data, $reduce_quantity);
}
```

Comment: I presume your dd isnt in your correct code. dd will end execution after a single loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looping over records to update them, use Eloquent instead as it's better suited for these operations:

```php
$inventory_items = InventoryItem::with('sorderParts')->get();

foreach ($inventory_items as $item) {
  $item->quantity = $item->solderParts->new_quantity;
  $item->save();
}
```

This requires you to define the relationship in your InventoryItem model.

```php
public function sorderParts()
{
  return $this->hasOne(SorderPart::class, 'inventory_id');
}
```

I've made some assumptions about your codebase with these examples, you'll have to configure it to match what you're working on, but the basic idea is we're using Eloquent to query tuples of InventoryItem and we're eager loading the SorderPart relationship so we don't execute a new query each time we access the relationship which would be an +1 query problem. We then loop over those results and save the updated values.

Comment: Call to undefined method stdClass::save(), also when I dump and die, it shows only one record, which is supposed to be more than that

Comment: Apologies, I posted that answer late and completely disregarded that you were using DB, not Eloquent. I've updated the comment for the change you need.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate from the bottom of my heart!